# Options window for drop-down too small?

Tags: html, user-interface, drop-down-menu, html-select

**When I try to open a drop-down, the [window is too small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FwUZ.png) for me to see any options.
 However, I know that the options do exist because they do appear when I use my arrow keys.**

When I add `size=10` to the select tag, like so: 
`<select size="10">` 
everything works fine. However this is not the interface I want.

**What are the possibilities that could be causing this issue?**

Comment: You should be able to use the select without specifying a size at all and still be able to see the options. We will need to see more of your code.

Comment: @KyleSposato This clearly doesn't happen in the problem described -- please see the link for an image of the problem.

Comment: Yeah that image doesn't really help. The default behavior of a select element is to show its child option elements. You must have an issue somewhere else in your code preventing the select from behaving properly.

Comment: I have a lot of options to show. If it works on one browser but does not on another, is this an issue with the browser showing the content, rather than my code?

Comment: Yeah it could be but you haven't really provided any code specific to your situation. Its hard to give a definitive answer without seeing your implementation.

Comment: I think my code is too long to post on here as it has too many <option></option> and all, but what I did notice is that as I commented out options, after a certain point, the "window" of the options I could choose showed more and more options. (I think it was 1 more option visible as I commented out 1 more <option></option>.)

Comment: Id suggest reading this and editing your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Its difficult to help when we can't see the implementation and a recreation of the problem.

Comment: You can set height or width of the select tag. Or also padding to make it visible more.

Comment: @Saurav This doesn't affect the window of the options that can be selected. It only makes the box you click to open the drop-down bigger.

Comment: What you want exactly can you post it through an image if you can't post your code. You can send an image for what you exactly want and what you have got now. Otherwise, it is difficult to help you.